# React-native resizing text components based on screen size

Tags: react-native

I would like to know how to properly handle different screen sizes in react-native. For example I have some screens which contain quite a few components, buttons and text. When there is too much text some components go off screen. I have set up a fake example in rnplay to illustrate the issue - https://rnplay.org/apps/OpZMxQ. Any pointers would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: you can use pixelratio param to resize the components.

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.39/docs/pixelratio.html#pixelratio

Comment: In the F8 App source code you can find an example for text resizing: https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/master/js/common/F8Text.js#L44

Comment: I tired both but couldn't get it to change much

Comment: I think you have two aproaches to take. First F8 as @martinarroyo suggested could be enough, secondly your app needs to know how to manage diferents sizes and It means you have to do it. For example, you must define two ways to render, one when the screen resolution is better than 1024x768, and other when it is worst. It is just an example

Comment: Even, if you have a very very very big screen, you are not going to render the same font, it would be huge. Take as an example the way youtube works: fonts have diferents sizes, that's right, but if you have a 40'' screen or a 20'' screen fonts seem to have the same size, into the bigger you´ll see more videos.
I hope to be clear enough

Comment: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-font-scale`  will scale fonts based on screen size

Comment: Yeah i understand, thank you. Just trying to find out what the best approach is to use with react-native. Thank you parker i might use that.